# Go , there is no parameter $1

Tags: sql, postgresql, templates, go

Im trying to get the values of the database by this way. But the compiler throw me an error when I go to /myapps direction.

Structure:

```
type App struct{
    Title string
    Author string
    Description string
}
```

Function:

```
func myappsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres"," user=postgres dbname=lesson4 host=localhost password=1234 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
        rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT title, author, description FROM apps
                                 WHERE title ILIKE $1
                                 OR author ILIKE $1
                                 OR description ILIKE $1`)
            defer rows.Close()

            if err != nil{
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            apps := []App{}
            for rows.Next(){
                b := App{}
                err := rows.Scan(&b.Title, &b.Author, &b.Description)

                if err != nil{
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
                apps = append(apps, b)
            }

            render(w, "myapps.html", map[string]interface{}{"apps" : apps})

        db.Close()
}
```

I read like this in the HTML:

```
{{ range .apps}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ .Title }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Author }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Description }}</td>
    <td> <form action="/delete">
          <p class="navbar-form navbar-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button> </p>
       </form></td>
  </tr>
{{ end  }}
```

The error is :   there is no parameter $1.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue, thank you anyways for your answers and help :)

I will post the working code:

Structure:

```
type App struct{
    Title string
    Author string
    Description string
}
```

Handler of Apps:

```
 db := SetupDB()

        rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT title, author, description FROM apps`)
            PanicIf(err)

            defer rows.Close()

            apps := []App{}
            for rows.Next(){
                b := App{}
                err := rows.Scan(&b.Title, &b.Author, &b.Description)
            PanicIf(err)

                apps = append(apps, b)
            }

            render(w, "myapps.html", map[string]interface{}{"apps" : apps})

        db.Close()
```

And the html:

```
{{ range .apps}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ .Title }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Author }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Description }}</td>
    <td> <form action="/delete">
          <p class="navbar-form navbar-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button> </p>
       </form></td>
  </tr>
{{ end  }}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass the parameters

```
title := '%the title%'
author := '%John%'
description := '%a book%'

rows, err := db.Query(`
    SELECT title, author, description
    FROM apps
    WHERE title ILIKE $1
          OR author ILIKE $2
          OR description ILIKE $3`
    , title, author, description
)
```

http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query

Use the `%` character to mean *match anything*

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: But I want to get values of the DB. this take values like this ones really?

Comment: I got the same code, and I got that error now :  pq: syntax error at or near "OR".

Comment: Postgres uses the $1 syntax, but the answer is correct, your code reference as parameter $1, but does not provide it. I assume you are trying to find if a given string (presumably from the request) is in any of those fields; make sure you provide the string as the last parameter to your Query.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring But if I put $1 in the three I got an error. Only shows the page If I put $1, $2, $3. But dont show the values of the table.

Comment: @devtreat Pass parameter values that exist in the table, not the ones I posted as example.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto But I only want to list the rows of the DB in my html. By this way only load me the html but without the values.